# How to declare class as global without code duplication in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to declare class as global without code duplication?

This doesn't work

```
declare global {
  class A {
    hi() { return "hi" }
  }
}

export {}
```

So I had to use code duplication [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8kUAzsfAII74HwAWAlgBQCUAXPMQC4z0B2i1AL65huRgHc+wFOPgk5vAJ7MAdJQC8haKQpUCDFjnhxOAVxi94AIgZX4w0SAAeABxQxOOQUA)

```
declare global {
  class A {
    hi(): string
  }
}

(window as any).A = class A { // Also why it doesn't work without `any`?
  hi() { return "hi" }
}

export {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I don't see anything great for this.  Without something like [microsoft/TypeScript#39504](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39504), you'll be forced to do at least some duplication.

One possible solution is the following, which has a fixed amount of overhead, which might be worth it to you if your class definition has more than just one or two methods/properties:

```
const _A = class A {
  hi() { return "hi" }
}

declare global {
  var A: typeof _A
  interface A extends InstanceType<typeof A> { }
}
window.A = _A; // or globalThis.A = _A;

export { }
```

First you implement your `A` class and assign it to a temporary, differently-named variable `_A`.  Then you can use `typeof _A` to refer to the type of that class constructor, and use it in to augment your global scope.  Class declarations introduce both a named *value* for the constructor and a named *type* for the instance type), so in order to augment the global scope with a class expression and `typeof`, you need to do both manually.  Hence the `var` for the constructor and the `interface` for the instance type.

(With something like a `typeof class` feature as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#41581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41581) this could be a little less painful, but for now this is the best I can do).

Note that the `interface A` type uses [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype); this will work reasonably well but has some edge cases; generic classes being a big one.  So you'll need to test this on your use cases.

Anyway, once the global scope knows about the global `A` class, you can just assign  the `_A` constructor to it without error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gQRgXhsANgQwhGSDeAUDDABYCWAFAJQz4wBOAplAK4NgwBEFXMAvoUGEAJkwyZmMAOboQAI0zo6xGADdJeAFwwoATwAOTEADN4CVeTBQmDE5mBM8MJgA8bYEbgCSkKJjBHABVDJgAefSNTPAA+OgEhQgB3KxEQJIA6JFREAG4YAHoCmBAGGTlFdCCKCCyUc1zCQjcDUth6YUIgA)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new property (say `A` class) to `window` like this:

```
declare global {
  class A {
    hi(): string
  }

  interface Window { AClass: A; }
}

window.AClass = window.AClass || {};

window.AClass.hi();
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8kUAzsfAII74HwAWAlgBQCUAXPMQC4z0B2i1AL65qfTiBgAzKGAQB1PsBQB3HBQDC0Uu3IBueMOG5lilQDpymkmQC88E7yXKLV0vAA%207nIN0iHTly1iMwYWX1wAegAqXEZ-FXgSRN4AT2YLeDsiN0o8AlDmNThOAFcYXngAIgZKg1xhKIiRXBAADwAHFBhObEEgA)